# into_sub_account(sub) encode the SAME adress for different sub

Tags: pallet, account, sub-account

Here is a simplified example of what I encounter:

I have this function in my pallet:

```
fn(...) -> ... {
    let idx = get_index(); //
    let address = T::PalletId::get().into_sub_account(idx);
    transfer(address, 1000); //i transfer the existential deposit on my new address, its 1000
    index::T::put(idx + 1);
}
```

and this test:

```
fn test_fn {
    assert_eq(Pallet::index(), 0) // pass
    assert_ok(Pallet::fn(...));   // pass
    assert_eq(Pallet::index(), 1) // pass
    assert_ok(Pallet::fn(...));   // pass
    assert_eq(Pallet::index(), 2) // pass
    assert_ok(Pallet::fn(...));   // pass

    assert_ok(Balances::free_balance(get_acc_id(0), 1000) // error: left = 3000, right = 1000
}

fn get_acc_id(index) -> AccountId {
    Pallet::get().into_sub_account(index)
}
```

I don't understand why i have this `error: left = 3000, right = 1000`, unless into_sub_account(0) and into_sub_account(2) give me the same output. Am I doing something wrong?

bonus: this test pass:

```
assert_eq!(get_account_id(0), get_account_id(100000));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are running into an issue which is noted here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10719

Specifically, `AccountIdConversion` is potentially truncating and can be non-unique. In this case, your tests probably uses an `AccountId` type with very few bytes, and in this case, your accounts are overlapping due to this flaw.

The solution is to update your tests to use a type with more bytes, like `AccountId32`, rather than something like `u64`.

Hopefully, by the time others find this issue, the PR resolving this will be merged.

Comment: Thanks, changing the type of AccountId in my mock runtime worked :)